# Restrict column with multiple values not appear if one condition is also met

Tags: sql, oracle

So my title might not make sense. Here's what I am trying to do.

```
C1      C2          C3

A1      yes         X1
A2      no          X1
A3      maybe       X1
A4      yes         X2
```

So I have a condition where C2 <>'no'. In this case I want the result to only include

```
C1     C2     C3
A4     yes    X2
```

Appreciate your help folks!

Comment: always nice to see what you have tried

Comment: This question isn't quite clear: what is multiple value, why exactly this row should survived, what has `C2<>'no'` to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `minus` to get a list of all `c3`s which don't have a `no` for `c2`. and select only those rows from the table.

```
 select * from table
 where c3 in(
 select distinct c3 from table
 minus
 select distinct from table where c2 = 'no' )
```

Comment: Thanks vkp, this worked! and sorry for not confirming earlier as I was away from my computer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
with x as (
    select 'a1' as col1, 'yes' as col2, 'x1' as col3 from dual
    union all
    select 'a2' as col1, 'no' as col2, 'x1' as col3 from dual
    union all
    select 'a3' as col1, 'maybe' as col2, 'x1' as col3 from dual
    union all
    select 'a4' as col1, 'yes' as col2, 'x2' as col3 from dual
)
select *
from x
where not exists (
    select 1
    from x x2
    where x2.col3 = x.col3
    and x2.col2 = 'no'
);
```

Output:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
a4  yes x2
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple NOT IN should do it.

```
Select * 
From   Table
Where  C3 Not In ( Select  C3 
                   From    Table 
                   Where   C2 = 'no')
```

Comment: beware of NULLs when using "not in" (if c3 has nulls, you won't get data)